# UIApplication delegate IOS9

Tags: ios9, uiapplicationdelegate

Hey there I found out that `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`

has been deprecated in IOS9 UIApplicationDelegate in favor of `application:openURL:options:`

if I still want to maintain IOS8 compatibility does that mean that I have to implement both methods? What the best practice?
Here is what I am doing:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    // implementation ios 8 and below
  }

  @available(iOS 9.0, *)
  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // implementation ios 9 and above 
    // access new IOS 9 stuff like UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey
  }
```